# Removing Non-Numeric Characters from String Fail in a Scenario + MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a migration script from MS SQL server 2000 to MS SQL Server 2012, I would like to migrate varchar field data to float, some of values in old data having non numeric data which I removed using below code, and it works in most of case, except below values where conversion fail, logically .(DOT) is valid value but due to multiple .DOT its fail.

I am thinking to ignore values where conversion fail, but haven't found to ignore it.

Column Values

> 1.2.4
>
> 5..4
>
> ..7.5.3

```
SELECT Left(SubString(field, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', field), 8000), 
                        PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(field, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', field), 8000) + 'X')-1)
```

---

After Suppress below is final code, which worked fine

```
CASE WHEN (len(field) - len(replace(field, '.', '')) <= 1 AND field!='.' ) THEN
CAST(ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(SubString(field, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', field), 8000), 
                PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(field, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', field), 8000) + 'X')-1) ,'-',''),'..','.'),'')
                as float)
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the dots, suppress (NULL) if > 1

```
select case 
   when len(field) - len(replace(field, '.', '')) > 1 then null 
   else Left(..) end
```

Or in a where clause:

```
where len(field) - len(replace(field, '.', '')) <= 1
```

Comment: Alex, Excellent Answer, Below is modified code, and it worked Well  CASE WHEN (len(field) - len(replace(field, '.', '')) <= 1) THEN
CAST(ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(SubString(field, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', field), 8000), 
                PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(field, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', field), 8000) + 'X')-1) ,'-',''),'..','.'),'')
                as float)
END